# Can't iterate JSON string from asp.net WCF service in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am new to objective-c but I am trying to render out a simple UItableview, filling it with data from my REST service coded in asp.net. The service takes data from SPs run on SQL servicer and using the JSONSerailzer class spits out a JSON string. I have verified it is a valid JSON string by pasting the output to an online JSON viewer.

Example as follows (This is exactly how my service returns it):

```
{"d":"[{\"callref\":12345,\"user\":\"foo\",\"name\":\"bar\"},{\"callref\":54321,\"user\":\"bar\",\"name\":\"foo\"}]"}
```

I can get the data in to objective-c fine via:

```
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

However when I try to step into this result either by casting as NSDictionary or NSArray but the result always ends up as NSCFString and because of that it crashes my code when I try to enter a for loop.

```
NSArray *allItems = [result objectForKey:@"d"];    
for (int i=0; i<allItems.count; ++i) {
    NSDictionary *item = [allItems objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *callref=[item objectForKey:@"callref"];
    NSString *user=[item objectForKey:@"user"];
    NSString *name=[item objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

What am I missing here? Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "d" data is "embedded JSON", meaning it must be deserialized separately, after the containing structure is deserialized.  Ie, run your `allItems` value through NSJSONSerialization again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON being returned from the server is not what you expect it to be, by the look of it.

It's a dictionary (see the outer `{` and `}`), however it contains a key of `"d"` and a **string** value of `"[{\"callref\" ..."` (note the first double-quote and the escaped inner double-quotes).

So first job is to fix the server, which is off-topic to your question.

After that, it should be as simple as:

```
NSDictionary* result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&error];
NSArray *keys = [result allKeys];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSArray *array = result[key];
    for (NSDictionary *item in array) {
        NSString *callref = item[@"callref"];
        NSString *user = item[@"user"];
        NSString *name = item[@"name"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a lot further along now I think. I have amended the output on the server to stream rather than string, which has removed the escape chars. This has also removed the prefixing "d". The output now looks like:

[{"callref":12345,"user":"foo","name":"bar"},{"callref":54321,"user":"bar","name":"foo"}]

and I am receiving an error message when entering the NSArray of: -[__NSCFArray allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Comment: @TonyLaw -- Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  The embedded JSON is an "array" of "objects", which maps to an NSArray of NSDictionarys.

Comment: trojanfoe, you kinda messed up.  You should iterate through the array, not use `allKeys`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @trojanfoe! I have it now.

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed; I've fixed it now (at least I think I have).